# Scilab: How to solve an ODE where dy/dt = filter(1, ar, y1)

Tags: ode, scilab

I want to simulate a time series `y1` with an AR(p) process, and then solve the differential equation `dy/dt = AR(p)(y1)`. This is the Scilab code I wrote (the AR coefficients are calculated with the `lev()` function and then normalized in a part of the code I omitted to keep it short).

```
  t = [0:0.1:2*%pi];
  y1 = sin(t);
  C = 1;
  y2 = -1*cos(t) + C;
  ar = [1.  - 0.0195380  - 0.0154317  - 0.0116690  - 0.0081661  -0.1015448]
   y1_m = filter(1, ar, y1); //Generates simulated series
  function y_m = far(t, y, ar, y1)
      y_m = filter(1, ar, y1);
  endfunction
  //Solves ODE
  y0 = y1(1); t0 = t(1);
  y2m = ode(y0, t0, t, list(far, ar));
  scf(1); plot(t, y2, '-k', t, y2m, '.k');
```

However, the code fails with message:

```
y2m = ode(y0, t0, t, list(far, ar_n));
                                  !--error 98
La variabile restituita dalla funzione argomento di Scilab non è corretta.
at line      26 of exec file called by :
```

How can I solve this ODE?

Added Case Description:
What I have is a system that performs certain operation on the input signal `Y`, which is a time series, producing an output `Z`. The system equations are known, so I can determine `Z` provided that `Y` is a known function of time.

And by writing that I realize where my mistake lies: with an AR model, I am expressing `Y` not as a function of time, but of its own past values.

So I should rather ask, how can I fit a function of time to a time series?

Comment: I noticed that you do ``ar = [...]; y1_m = filter(1, ar_n, y1)``. Shouldn't ``ar`` be named ``ar_n``? If yes, I ran you code on Scilab 6.0.0 and there was no error.

Comment: Your ODE function `far` should depend on `y`. In `list(far, ar_n)` there is no argument for the place of `y1`. If I interpret this right, are you trying to solve `y' = T^(-1)*y` where `T` s a Töplitz matrix defined by the entries of `ar`?

Comment: @luispauloml. In fact you caught a mistake I made while inputting the code in Stackoverflow. I corrected the question,

Comment: @LutzL. Also using `y2m = ode(y0, t0, t, list(far, ar, y1));` the result is the same. I am not familiar with the Toplitz matrix, so I cannot say.

Comment: From the look of it, `far` returns a constant, so the solution should be linear functions. Is that the desired result?

Comment: Please describe what exactly you want to compute, I have the feeling that using `ode` is completely inappropriate for that task, as it looks like you are simulating a discrete dynamical system.

Comment: No, it's not. The desired result should be close to `y2`, the analytical solution.

Comment: Yes, I think this problem requires a complete explanation. Please stay tuned for it.

Comment: Indeed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model there is no mention of differential equations.

Comment: In `dy/dt = AR(p)(y1)` the right side is a constant. Or one has to describe what `y` is in relation to `y1` and what dimensions are involved. By itself, the right side should return a finite sequence. You seem to consider `y` to be scalar.

Comment: Can it be that you want to compute and confirm the discretized linear system for a given and perhaps unknown continuous linear system?

Comment: I added an extended description of my case.